# Object is null in JSX tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I'm writing an application with a spring boot backend and react.js frontend. I am having an extremely annoying, and basic problem with react, and I'm not a very experienced JS developer...I'm a Java dev.

```
render() {
       console.log(this.videoAreaData)

        return (
            <div className='lib-modal'>
                <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>List of Available Libraries</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>{libs}</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
{
  "libs": [
    {
      "name": "videos",
      "library": null
    }
  ]
}
```

So then I add

```
console.log(this.videoAreaData.libs)
```

and get this following output

```
[
  {
    "name": "videos",
    "library": null
  }
]
```

So to test printing the first element I should use this.videoAreaData.libs[0] obviously right? Apparently not

```
TypeError: this.videoAreaData.libs is undefined[Learn More]
```

What I want to do is iterate over the array in my JSX code using .map, but the object is literally always undefined! I've tried using setState with a const and all kinds of stuff! The data is passed from my parent app.js class which uses this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    libraryAccessor.listLibraries().then(libs => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, show: false, libraries: libs })
    })
}
```

libs is then pasted as a parameter into my code using a property like this

```
        <LibraryLister libs={libraries} ref="libraries"></LibraryLister>
```

then it goes to the constructor of LibraryLister here

```
videoAreaData
constructor(videoAreaData) {
    super(videoAreaData)
    this.videoAreaData = videoAreaData
}
```

Now I assume all of that is done correctly, as it's non-null in my render method. If I put console.log(videoAreaData) within the JSX tags in a {} it's not null either, so it's *definitely* not supposed to be!

Here is what I finally want to do:

```
            <Modal.Body>
                {(this.videoAreaData.libs.map((library)=> {
                    return <p className="libname"> library.name </p>
                }))}
            </Modal.Body>
```

I feel like I'm doing something very very wrong here. That being said I have another project using the exact same stack, but made in typescript, and it works fine doing almost exactly this. Typescript is super irritating to use though, so I'd uh...prefer not to. Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT: Full code https://pastebin.com/daipM2gY

Also this alternate version of my render method prints the data as expected, so it...should not be undefined

```
render() {
    console.log("PRINTING VID DATA: "+this.videoAreaData)
    console.log(this.videoAreaData)
    return (
        <div className='lib-modal'>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>List of Available Libraries</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {console.log("PRINTIN BODY")}
                    {console.log(this.videoAreaData)}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Output:

```
PRINTIN BODY
{
  "libs": [
    {
      "name": "videos",
      "library": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does the parent component do in its `render` method while `isLoading` is `true`?

Comment: Is `this.videoAreaData.libs`'s value coming from an API call? If so, then it means you're mounting a component using its value before its value has been returned.

Comment: @HenryWoody the parent component does this
if(isLoading) return <pre>Loading...</pre>

Comment: @SamVK Yes it's coming from an API call to my spring boot backend. However I can print the object to the console in *exactly* the place it's saying is null, so that's empirically not the case right?

isLoading is set to true while it does the API call, and then once it's false everything else kicks in. The object is printed to the console just fine it's not until I try to access one of the indexes or call .map that it says it's undefined :/


Here are my 2 classes: https://pastebin.com/daipM2gY

Comment: What happens if you delete `this.setState({isLoading: true})` in `componentDidMount` and instead just set `isLoading: true` as the initial `state`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to study react

React’s props don’t work your post.

First you have to edit your videoAreaData constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.videoAreaData = this.props.videoAreaData;
}
```

I recommend to read props in http://reactjs.org/docs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Popover, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';
// My components
import Navigator from './components/Navigator';
import LibraryLister from './components/LibraryLister';
import LibraryAccessor from './accessors/LibraryAccessor';
var loadingChildren = {};
var libraryAccessor = new LibraryAccessor();
var jsAccessor = new LibraryAccessor();

export default class App extends Component {
    // React Component constructor parameter is `props`
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    open = () => {
        this.refs.navigator.open()
    }

    openLibs = () => {
        this.refs.libraries.open();
    }

    setLoading(refName, value) {
        loadingChildren[refName].delete(refName);
        if (loadingChildren.size < 1) {
            // this.state = { isLoading: value }
            // if you change state, you have to use setState; it's very very important.
            // setState function is asynchronous because it relate performance.
            this.setState({
                isLoading: value
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, libraries } = this.state;

        console.log(libraries) // check please~!
        if(isLoading) return <pre>Loading...</pre>

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Your Server</h1>
                </header>
                <Button onClick={this.open}>Show Navigator</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.openLibs}>Show Libraries</Button>
                <Navigator ref="navigator"></Navigator>
                <LibraryLister libs={libraries} ref="libraries"></LibraryLister>
            </div>
        );
    }

    getLibraries = (libraries) => {
        this.setState({ 
            isLoading: false,
            libraries
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        libraryAccessor
        .listLibraries()
        .then(this.getLibraries);
    }

}
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import LibraryAccessor from '../accessors/LibraryAccessor';
import './navigator.css';

var libraryAccessor = new LibraryAccessor();
var librarylist = [];

export default class LibraryLister extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loadModal: false 
        };
        this.videoAreaData = props.videoAreaData
    };

    render() {
        console.log("PRINTING VID DATA: "+this.videoAreaData)
        console.log(this.videoAreaData)
        return (
            <div className='lib-modal'>
                <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>List of Available Libraries</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>

                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

    close = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, show: false });
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, show: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it! I've read the docs several times, and I've actually made several applications in typescript. Not sure why it's breaking so much in regular js, but I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong. Also I was using this.state = {videoAreaData: data} previously. I know that's the preferred way, but I changed it to a field in the hopes it would work :/

Comment: @Redmancometh now it's okay I want to read your all .jsx give me your code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/daipM2gY

2 classes the top being the App.js and the bottom being the LibraryLister

Answer (score 0):

So I uh figured out what I was doing wrong actually. Nothing to do with the state (the isLoading stuff on componentLoad worked fine as it did in another project) but the POJO I was sending.

So here's what happened: this.state.libraries[x] was in fact undefined, because this.state.libraries was actually an object. Containing another object called libraries which was the array from my POJO.

My POJO I was sending had "libraries" as the root object with an array inside of it. It was then being packed into the state as libraries, and so I had to use this.state.libraries.libraries[x]

Really stupid problem, but glad it's solved.

Thanks for your help guys!

Final code for those interested:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import LibraryAccessor from '../accessors/LibraryAccessor'
import './navigator.css'


var libraryAccessor = new LibraryAccessor()
var librarylist = []

export default class LibraryLister extends React.Component {
    state = { loadModal: false, libs: [] }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ...this.state,
            libs: props
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.libs.libs[0])
        return (
            <div className='lib-modal'>
                <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>List of Available Libraries</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        {this.state.libs.libraries.map(item=> {
                            console.log("ITEM")
                        })}
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

    close = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, show: false });
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, show: true });
    }

}
```